# Calculate distances in a kind of "bag of words" approach

Tags: python, count, distance

My code runs but the output of my function is always `0.0`. My code calls `.txt` files and creates a matrix where each `.txt` file represents a line in the matrix and each word in the `.txt` file has its own column in the respective line in the matrix.

I compare the lines pairwise. I want to count how often each word of the union of both lines occurs. However, although the code runs I get the wrong result (`0.0`).

I thought I might have an error in the matrix that I use for the function, but the matrix looks good.

Strange thing is that if I create to lists manually:

```
a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
b = ["b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

it works, but when I change to:

```
a = ["word 1", "word 2", "word 3", "word 4"],
b = ["word 2","word 3","word 4","word 5",]
```

the result is again `0.0`. I am confused!

My code:

```
def bow_distance(a, b):

    p = 0

    if len(a) > len(b):
        max_words = len(a)
    else:
        max_words = len(b)

    list_words_ab = list(set(a) | set(b))

    len_bow_matrix = len(list_words_ab)
    bow_matrix = numpy.zeros(shape = (3, len_bow_matrix), dtype = str)

    while p < len_bow_matrix:
        bow_matrix[0, p] = str(list_words_ab[p])
        p = p+1

    p = 0   

    while p < len_bow_matrix:
        bow_matrix[1, p] = a.count(bow_matrix[0, p])
        bow_matrix[2, p] = b.count(bow_matrix[0, p])
        p = p+1

    p = 0
    overlap = 0

    while p < len_bow_matrix:
        abs_difference = abs(float(bow_matrix[1, p]) - float(bow_matrix[2, p]))
        overlap = overlap + abs_difference
        p = p+1

    return (overlap/2)/max_num_parts


    # Calculate the distances

i = 1
j = 1

while i < num_of_txt + 1:

    print(i)
    newfile = open("TXT_distance_" + str(i)+".txt", "w")

    while j < num_of_txt + 1:
        newfile.write(str(bow_distance(text_word_matrix[i-1], text_word_matrix[j-1])) + " ")
        j = j+1

    newfile.close()
    j = 1
    i = i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first sight I see two failures here:

```
a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"], <----- comma here 
b = ["b", "c", "d", "e"]
it works, but when I change to:

a = ["word 1", "word 2", "word 3", "word 4"], <----- and here 
b = ["word 2","word 3","word 4","word 5",] <----- and here inside the list
```

Comment: There's also an extra comma after `"word 5"` that needs to be removed.

Comment: The comma after word 5 doesn't matter as it's fine to have trailing commas in lists. However, the comma *after* the list definition, where `a` is defined, makes `a` a tuple with a single value (i.e. the array itself), and is probably throwing off your logic.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm sorry that I put the commas in. They are not in the code and I used them in an attempt to make my post clearly arranged. The commas are not the problem since they are not in my code. Any other ideas?

Comment: I tried to solve the problem for a few more hours without success. I import the lists (a,b) from an excel file. Strange thing is that the calculation works if the lists only consist of one-digit strings (e.g. ["a", "b", "c", "d"]). As soon as I have more than one-digit strings (e.g. ["a", "b", "c", "d"]) the calculation fails. Any idea? I'm frustrated!